# How to setup pubsub in MQ v-8 in distributed mode from One QM to anothe QM

Tags: mq

I am able to create pubsub setup on Local QM
BUt I want to create Pubsub setup from TEST to TEST1 Qmgr. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Can you please add details on what you tried, why it's not working, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this cookbook in [KnowledgeCenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q113890_.htm) helps you